# jQuery load() function - Couldn't get the height from dynamically loaded header content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I have designed A header and i display it dynamically using load() function. After loading the header, i tried to get the height of the header.

For that, I have written code. But that code is not working properly. I couldn't get the height of the element that has dynamically loaded.

**This is the Content i use to display dynamically:**

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 header-lft-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">PROJECTS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">PEOPLE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**This is the tag i use to display the header content using load() method:**

```
<div class="header-control"></div>
```

**This is the jQuery code i use to get the header height.**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        alert($(".header").outerHeight(true));
    });
});
```

Comment: Try putting the outerheight function in the done function of your load call.

Comment: Ref: *"For that, I have written correct code. But that code is not working properly."* How can code be correct and not work properly at the same time?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - Don't get me wrong. I mean its working fine, if i use header content in the page. But when i use load() method, not working. Besides, i'm new to this.

Comment: @imvain2 - I tried. It returns only 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following code, it might help you.

> ```
>  $("button").click(function(){   $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt",
>  function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
>  if(statusTxt == "success")
>   alert("External content loaded successfully!");
>  if(statusTxt == "error")
>   alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);   }); });
> ```